# How to change upload path to public_html instead of public laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

i use laravel backpack and i try to upload images. in local working. but in server the image uploaded to public, and not displaying in site i try change disk and in fileSystem but nothing changed

//model

```
 public function setPosterAttribute($value)
    {
        $attribute_name = "poster";
        $disk = "public";
        $destination_path = "uploads/products/posters";

        // if the image was erased
        if ($value==null) {
            // delete the image from disk
            \Storage::disk($disk)->delete($this->{$attribute_name});

            // set null in the database column
            $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = null;
        }

        // if a base64 was sent, store it in the db
        if (starts_with($value, 'data:image'))
        {
            // 0. Make the image
            $image = \Image::make($value);
            // 1. Generate a filename.
            $filename = md5($value.time()).'.jpg';
            // 2. Store the image on disk.
            \Storage::disk($disk)->put($destination_path.'/'.$filename, $image->stream());
            // 3. Save the path to the database
            $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = $destination_path.'/'.$filename;
        }
    }
```

//fileSystem

```
    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path(),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in your public array, the root is set to `public_path()` which is the path to your `public` folder. If you want to change that, you should should your configuration to the following:

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => base_path('public_html'),
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```